# I am trying to change the label of another viewcontroller when I press one of the cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

Here is the code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tasksTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    string = cell.textLabel?.text
    detail.TextLabel.text = string
}
```

The text label I am trying to change is `detail.textLabel.text`. I get the error `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` on the third line in the function. Do I need a `UITableViewDataSource` or `UITableViewDelegate`?

Comment: Have you defined the variable `string` before?

Comment: @kabiroberai, he must've. Otherwise this wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: oh right, I forgot about that

Comment: You should unwrap this label. Change second line to `string = cell.textLabel!.text`. It's most likely not the case for the crash though. How do you initialize the `detail` and the `TextLabel`?

Comment: You should really look into using a delegate for this. It might help solve your problem.

Comment: Whenever I try it says UITABLEVIEW delegate does not confor with MasterViewController

Comment: @AryaK wait so you haven't marked your class as a `UITableViewDelegate`?

Comment: no, I havent marked my class as a UITableViewController